# Apache memory usage control out of control

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, memory-usage

I have apache2 running on ubuntu 10.04 with 512mb ram. It all seems ok, until i start start making requests to the server. When I watch my memory usage, it jumps up about 5-10% every time I browse to another page. I am assuming this is new apache processes running to server the content. I am not bothered about that, but it doesn't come back down when I stop requesting pages.

I am using Django and wsgi if that makes any difference.

EDIT:

from: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 3

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
StartServers          1
MinSpareServers       1
MaxSpareServers       5
MaxClients           15
MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>



<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
StartServers          2
MinSpareThreads      25
MaxSpareThreads      75
ThreadLimit          64
ThreadsPerChild      25
MaxClients          150
MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>



<IfModule mpm_event_module>
StartServers          2
MaxClients          150
MinSpareThreads      25
MaxSpareThreads      75
ThreadLimit          64
ThreadsPerChild      25
MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

I already edited the mpm_prefork_module to be smaller, but that didn't fix it!

Comment: Avoid mod_wsgi embedded mode and prefork if at all possible. See 'http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/load-spikes-and-excessive-memory-usage.html'. Same issue for mod_wsgi embedded mode as for mod_python. Use of prefork means configuring/tuning Apache MPM settings for far persistent Python web application rather than defaults which are setup for static files and PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the link.Sounds like what I may be looking for. It's not working though :-)

Answer (score 1):

Can you post here what are the settings of your apache

`MaxRequestsPerChild`

`MaxClients`

also some top output or whatever you are seeing when it jumps could be great to help us understand and explain where memory is going.

Comment: I have already modified the mpm_prefork_module but I don;t think that helped.  Thanks for looking

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't come back down.  Its only an issue if you're running **out** of memory.  Otherwise most software will use as much memory as possible and keep using it.

This sounds like working as expected.  A few apache children start up, consume some memory, and stay running with in the bounds of max and min spare servers.

You can browse the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html) and make more adjustments if you like.  Say reduce MaxSpareServers.  Then you won't have as many apache processes hanging around.

Comment: I reduced the numbers and now it sits at about 70% of memory usage. If I happen to run any larger memory processes off apache it should give me some head room